# Magento 2: Get all bundle products

Tags: product, database, magento2.4, bundled-product, table

So I have to create a report (SQL Script) which has all the bundle products and all its customizable options.
I can get list of all the bundle products using this query.

```
select entity_id, type_id, sku, has_options from catalog_product_entity where type_id='bundle';
```

In catalog_product_entity, I assume that entity_id is the primary key.

Now I want all the options associated with bundle product.

[image]

[image]

which tables should I refer to? I know catalog_product_bundle_option and catalog_product_bundle_option_value can give me option title but when I try to join using parent_id with entity_id it doesn't return anything.

Can anyone explain table structure to me or which tables should I refer to then that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you should be able to join `catalog_product_entity` and `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` on:

```
catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_bundle_option_value.parent_product_id
```

However, if you look at the table definition for `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`, `parent_product_id` is not a key and no database-defined constraint binds it to `catalog_product_entity.entity_id`. The relationship is maintained outside of the database, meaning that you have to know and trust Magento's logic.

As an alternative, you should also be able to join `catalog_product_entity` and `catalog_product_bundle_option` on:

```
catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_bundle_option.parent_id
```

And additionally be able to join `catalog_product_bundle_option` and `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` on:

```
catlog_product_bundle_option.option_id = catalog_product_bundle_option_value.option_id
```

Nesting these two will allow you to create a query that effectively joins `catalog_product_entity` and `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` on actual keys.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it.